# Updating Mule OAuth client scopes

Tags: oauth, mule

I am trying to add scopes to a `org.mule.modules.oauth2.provider.client.Client` object used in our authentication system, but when I call the `setScopes` method on an object I fetched from the database it causes the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.addAll(Collections.java:1085)
```

Is there any way I can mutate the scopes save for deleting the object and then re-creating it with the appropriate scopes ?

Comment: This is potentially a bug: if `setScopes` is accessible then it should work, not throw this exception. Since this is an Enterprise Edition feature, I suggest you report it to MuleSoft directly.

Answer (score 0):

The oauth 2 module provides xml-based message processors to update the scopes of any given user, I would encourage you implement this logic within a mule flow, please see the documentation:

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Creating+an+OAuth+2.0a+Web+Service+Provider

I.E you can delete the client and re-create it with different scopes:

```
<oauth2-provider:create-client clientId="" config-ref="">
    <oauth2-provider:scopes />
</oauth2-provider:create-client>
```